# String concatenation error in php

Tags: php, sql

In my code I'm trying to accept input through a webpage from the user and create SQL query by dynamically creating where clause based on the input from the user. However it looks like I'm unable to correctly concatenate strings.

```
$whereclause .= "AND niche ='".$niche."'";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM merc WHERE 1 = 1".$whereclause."") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You're missing a space between the 1 and the whereclause.

Comment: **By building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Comment: @AndyLester can you tell, what is your favorite and why when considering `ADO/PDO/ODBC`?

Comment: I have no preference.  I've always used PDO but you may have different needs.  The key is to stop building SQL statements from untrusted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid SQL Injection conditions while writing queries and use [mysqli](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_mysql](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead of mysql.

Try following query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM merc WHERE 1 = 1 ".$whereclause."") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
```

space was missing in your query.

Answer (score 0):

A space is missing.

```
$whereclause = "AND niche = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($niche)."'";
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM merc WHERE 1 = 1 ".$whereclause") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
```

Make sure when getting input from a user it is not passed unmolested to MySQL. Doing otherwise will open the application up to a ton of problems, most specifically SQL Injection. Also, the mysql_* functions have been deprecated. Moving to mysqli_* is highly suggested.

Comment: Hi SamA, Thanks for the help. When i use your code i get these errors Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given 

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given 

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: PHP.net has a great set of docs on all functions. Turns out to use the mysqli query function procedurally, one needs to call it like this "mysqli::query". See docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php